# Why does Powershell DSC MOF generation does not work for me?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I am trying to write my first Powershell DSC script which seems simple enough, unless of cource it does not work.

My script is called ScriptFolderConfig.ps1
Here is my script:

```
configuration ScriptFolder
{
    param ($Node)

    node $Node
    {
        File ScriptFiles
        {
            SourcePath = "\\BRPSTFSBUILD01\Drops\share"
            DestinationPath = "C:\scripts"
            Ensure = "Present"
            Type = "Directory"
            Recurse = $true
        }
    }
}
```

From the folder that contains the script I run .\ScriptFolderConfig.ps1 with out error.
Then I try to run ScriptFolder, and I receive the error:

> ScriptFolder : The term 'ScriptFolder' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + ScriptFolder
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ScriptFolder:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

From the folder that contains your script run

```
. .\ScriptFolderConfig.ps1 # "." will load your function
```

Then try again.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help. Can you explain why this works, or is necessary in my case but apparently is not necessary for all of the examples I have found.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm sure that you will found the answer to your question in this great post. http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/08/10/how-to-reuse-windows-powershell-functions-in-scripts.aspx

Comment: The reason it's necessary is that when you use execute the `.ps1` script, it's self contained. The variables and functions and state that are used within it happen in their own scope. By dot sourcing it, you are bringing the script file into your current scope, as though you had typed all that at the command line. Many examples out there execute the configuration _within_ the ps1 file, right after it's defined, so the entire operation happens in that scope and dot sourcing is not necessary.